# What would be the compositum $K \cdot \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt u)$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider $K$ be an unramified extension of $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$.

> I want to compute the compositum $K \cdot \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt u)$, where $u^2=-1$.

Since $K$ is unramified extension, we have $K \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n)$.

So we have $K \cdot \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt u) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n) \cdot \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt u).$

What would be the exact computation ?

> Is $K \cdot \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt u)=K(\sqrt u)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $u=-1$ ? If so then there are 3 cases for $\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{-1})$ depending on $p\bmod 4$. And yes obviously if $L\subset K$ and $\alpha\in \overline{K},L\subset\overline{K}$ then $K L(\alpha) = K(\alpha)$. You are probably misunderstanding what is the compositum of two fields algebraic on each other.

Comment: @reuns, yes, I meant $u^2=-1$. But I think more about $u$ here. For $p \geq 3$, consider the $(p^n-1)$ th root, say $\zeta_{p^n-1}$, of $-1$. Then my $u$ is just $(\zeta_{p^n-1})^{\frac{p^n-1}{2}}$ so  that $u^2=(\zeta_{p^n-1})^{p^n-1}=-1$. That is what is my $u$.

Comment: If $\zeta_n$ means a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then it is not necessarily true in your situation that $K \subseteq \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_n)$. Consider e.g. $n=p-1$, or $n=2$. Do you maybe mean $\zeta_{p^n-1}$ there? --- Also, to make 100% sure, you mean the extension $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt u)$ but $u^2=-1$ (and not $u=-1$)? In other words, the field you want to compose $K$ with is the cyclotomic field containing the *eighth*, not the *fourth* roots of unity? In other words, you are looking at $\mathbb Q_(\sqrt[4]{-1})$, not $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{-1})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reuns points out in a comment, if $L$ is any field, and $K \vert L$ an extension, and both $K$ and an element $\alpha$ are contained in a common extension $F \vert L$ (say, e.g., $F = $ an algebraic closure of $L$ or $K$), then the compositum is

$$K.L(\alpha) = K(\alpha).$$

This equality is so immediate from the definitions that I would have a hard time explaining it further.

In your case $L=\mathbb Q_p$ and $\alpha$ is some primitive root of unity; I am still not sure if you mean a fourth root of unity, i.e. $\alpha^2=-1$, i.e. $\alpha=\zeta_4$, or an eighth root of unity, i.e. $\alpha^4=-1$, i.e. $\alpha=\zeta_8$, but in both cases it is straightforward to determine that field.

**Case 1**: $p$ odd. Then because $2^n$-th roots of unity generate unramified extensions, it's immediate that $$\zeta_4 \in K \Leftrightarrow 4 \vert (p^n-1) \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1 (4) \text{ or } n \text{ is even}$$
$$\zeta_8 \in K \Leftrightarrow 8 \vert (p^n-1)\Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1 (8) \text{ or } n \text{ is even}$$
meaning that precisely in these cases, the compositum $=K(\alpha)$ is just $K$ itself. This also tells us (because for each degree $d$ there is a *unique* unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ in a given algebraic closure, and they are all cyclic) that in *all remaining cases*, $K(\alpha) \vert K$ is of degree $2$ i.e. the unique quadratic unramified extension of $K$.

**Case 2**: $p=2$. Now $\mathbb Q_2(\zeta_4)$ and $\mathbb Q_2(\zeta_8)$ are both totally *ramified* extensions, of degree $2$ and $4$ respectively. But since $K\vert \mathbb Q_2$ is unramified, and regardless of what else it is, ramification theory forces $K(\zeta_4) \vert K$ and $K(\zeta_8) \vert K$ to be totally ramified extensions of degree $2$ and $4$, respectively, as well.